# Google Tag Manager with scroll.depth.js

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager to do google analytics for the current site.
Now, we would like to know how far people scroll on our sites.
So I used a plug-in called jquery.scrollDepth.js

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.scrolldepth.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$.scrollDepth({
  elements: ['#hero', '#small_part', '#lines', '#model_part', '#intro', '#charger',      '#science', '#resell'],
  percentage: false,
  pixelDepth: false,
  nonInteraction: false,
  eventHandler: function(data) {
      }
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

the codes are like this in my site.
And then, I followed the lead of http://andygibson.us/2013/10/track-scroll-depth-using-google-tag-manager/ 
But I got lost at the Track Type Event picture.

I couldn't find anything like this at my google tag manager dashboard.
And I absolutely have no idea of what i am doing, whether it's right or wrong.
Please give some help.

Comment: It's the same tag template that you would use for Analytics pageviews - there is a dropdown that can be changed from pageviews to events (or other interaction types).

Answer (score 0):

Ill make this very simple for you.

Using the new Google Tag Manager (V2) follow the directions below.

1 : Create a new tag and paste [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z7m6v0hh/) code inside. Name the tag, Scroll Tracking and have the tag fire on all pages.

```
<script></script>
```

2 : Create a custom event trigger, name it "scroll percentage". Create the trigger with the following parameters.

- Event Name : "ScrollDistance"
- Event Action : contains "Percentage"

3 : Create a new tag with the following parameters

- Product : "google analytics"
- Tag Type : "Universal Analytics"
- Configure : Event :
             {{event Category}}, {{event Action}}, {{event Label}}
- Fire On : "Scroll Distance"